# Password encryption before form submit

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I'm creating a website for some company I work with. It includes user authentification. The database stores the hashed passwords.

At some point on a certain page, the user should be able to sign in via a popup. That requires an asynchronous request to a php file that will request the database with the password.

Which leads me to my question : should I use Javascript to hash the password before it is sent in my asynchronous request, to prevent, for example, man-in-the-middle attacks or things like that ? I don't know if the site will be using HTTPS yet.

Thanks.

Comment: If you send a hashed password, and the man-in-the-middle intercepts that... Well, guess what, they'd just have to send the same hashed password to the server to imitate your request. **If you send a hashed password, then the hashed password _is_ your password.** You gain nothing.

Comment: Without HTTPS you don't have security. Also +1 for @deceze. Security is hard. Be careful or you will get burned.

Comment: This is not a bad question, one can find a lot of tutorials recommending client side hashing, so i cannot understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side hashing can never replace server side hashing. A man in the middle can not only use the "encrypted" password directly as the new password, he can also strip away the JavaScript which encrypts the password. Even worse he could send a copy of the real password to another server, so you would not even recognize the change.

The only option for a website is to use an encrypted HTTPS/SSL connection. There you can send the password plaintext, SSL takes care of secure transport.

Answer (score 2):

Sending hashed passwords isn't going to stop anyone sniffing your connection. The HTTP request contains the hashed pass, which is clearly readable since the request itself isn't encrypted.

If you want to be safe from this sort of stuff, use HTTPS